# Re -size the pop up window in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i need to re- size the pop up window

i wrote the following code and what to do to resise the window.

```
  onclick="openAccountPickerDialog(window, document.forms[0].FDOPAC, '@Url.Content("~/")AccountLookup/_LookupIndex/')"
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of openAccountPickerDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your implementation of openAccountPickerDialog, it will be hard to answer this question.  However, you do have control over the windows you open through JavaScript.  For example:

```
window.open ("http://yoursite.com", "yourwindow","width=100,height=100");
```

A good walkthrough is located here:

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Cheers.